# Magento 2 custom module: group by & count admin grid results, display totals at top of admin grid page

Tags: magento2

I'm writing a custom module for managing specialised processing of order line items, and need to run some additional queries based on the filtered results in an admin grid.

These queries would need to calculate the total number of products grouped by SKUs, and then display them at the top of the page. It's important that the pagination does not affect the totals, it would need count across all found rows, disregarding any limits.

So, as you can see in the attached screenshot, I would like to run a query to show that there are 2 "Jacket Blue" and 2 "Jacket Red" and place this at the top of the page.

[image: Admin grid screenshot]

Any tips would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in _prepareCollection()

```
$collection->groupByAttribute('sku')->addExpressionAttributeToSelect("count", 'COUNT({{sku}})', 'sku');
```

And add below code in _prepareColumns()

```
$this->addColumn('count', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Count'),
        'width' => '25px',
        'index' => 'count',
    ));
```